# Check if stdout supports unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, stdout

I would normally do this if I wanted to print Unicode:

```
print("There are ", end="")
try:
    print(u"\u221E", end="")  # ∞
    unicode_support = True
except UnicodeError:
    print("infinity", end="")
    unicode_support = False
print(" ways to get Unicode wrong.")

if unicode_support:
    print(u"\U0001F440 see you have a Unicode font.")
else:
    print("You do not have Unicode support.")
```

This won't work if I want to return a Unicode string from a method or something similar, as Python will always understand string literals with Unicode in them and only throws this error when printing to something without Unicode support. I want to do something like this:

```
import sys as _sys

UNICODE_SUPPORT = _sys.stdout.unicode_support

def get_heart():
    if UNICODE_SUPPORT:
        return u"\u2665"  # ♥
    return "heart"

print("I{}U".format(get_heart.upper()))
```

I would like the equivalent of `sys.stdout.supports_unicode` to be `True` if the current stdout supports Unicode else `False`.

Comment: Check the source of the click library, I think that library has this issue handled.

Comment: All stdout encodings support a *section* of the Unicode standard.. Care to define what portion you care about? Latin-1 covers the first 256 codepoints, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a hack, but something like that, maybe:

```
 UNICODE_SUPPORT = sys.stdout.encoding in ('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-32', 'UTF-32LE', 'UTF32BE')
```

Or (credit to Martijn Pieters):

```
 UNICODE_SUPPORT = sys.stdout.encoding.lower().startswith('utf')
```

Simply said, *Unicode* is a huge list of all the characters used in writing language all around the world. Including ancient languages and many common and not-so-common symbols ([U+1F4A9](http://codepoints.net/U+1F4A9)). Each item in that list is called a *code point* and is identified by a number.

UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are *encoding* specially designed to be able to encode *all* code points to sequences of bytes. UTF-16 and UTF-32 being fixed-size multi-byte encoding exists both a big-endian and little-endian.

Unicode being designed a *universal*, by definition any encoding other than `UTF-...` support only a subset of Unicode. cp1252 and iso-8859-15 as such encoding, supporting (partially) the latin subset of Unicode.

Comment: See, but my encoding is `'cp1252'`, which *does* support Unicode, so this won't work.

Comment: @Reticality Then, you have to define exactly what is for you "to support unicode" as `cp1252` has obviously no mapping for most of the unicode code-points...

Comment: @Sylvain I will make a way (Through a lot of probably copy-pasting) to turn encoding into amount of code-points.

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.stdout.encoding
```

is `None` when there's no encoding set for it, e.g when redirecting to a file without special precautions, so e.g a `print(u'fo\xe0ba')` will fail (trying to use the `ascii` encoding and failing).

Added: note that most encodings are **not** "universal" -- each supports only a **subset** of Unicode.  "Supports Unicode" is one thing; "Supports **all** of Unicode" (aka "uses a universal encoding") is another.

UTF-8 is by far the most popular universal encoding, though you may, very occasionally, encounter UTF-16, or even UTF-32 (personally I've never met the latter "in the wild":-).

BTW, even though a certain device supports, e.g, utf-8, that does **not** imply it will have the right glyphs in its font repertory to display every single code-point readably and unambiguously -- that's a very different issue.

Comment: Is `None` the only thing returnable when Unicode isn't supported? (i.e. are there any encodings which don't support Unicode?)

Comment: @Reticality, several encodings may support only **parts** of Unicode -- for example, `ISO-8859-1` supports only the first 256 codepoints, `ascii` only the first 128 ones, and so on.  In fact few encodings, such as `utf8`, are "universal".  But "Unicode isn't supported" is quite a different issue!  Let me edit the answer to clarify this.